# Embed facebook 360 video in UIWebView

Tags: facebook, video, uiwebview, 360-degrees

Facebook has launched option to embed 360° video in web app. I am trying show embedded video in UIWebView. But its not working.

Here is my code,

```
let iStrEmbed = "<iframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook%2Fvideos%2F10153231379946729%2F&width=500&show_text=false&height=281&appId\" width=\"500\" height=\"281\" style=\"border:none;overflow:hidden\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowTransparency=\"true\"></iframe>"

webVW.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webVW.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
webVW.loadHTMLString(iStrEmbed, baseURL: nil);
```

I have noticed its not working in even safari of mobile. Its working fine in all browsers on mac.

Is it supported only for desktop as of now?

Comment: I have the same issue , do you solve it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of now, yes- desktop only.  I've had the most success on our custom-WordPress productions with the following hack via [Facebook for Developers platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/?prefill_href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FHealthHouseKC%2Fvideos%2F634994209981931%2F#configurator).  Please try the following steps:

1. Upon selecting your Facebook360 video or photo, click on the ellipsis menu and select **Embed**.

[image]

2. Next, a dialogue-window will prompt- click on **Advanced Settings**.

[image]

3. Clicking the aforementioned will direct you to the Facebook for Developers platform; [click here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/?prefill_href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FHealthHouseKC%2Fvideos%2F634994209981931%2F#configurator) to see the instance created for the subject example.
4. Click on the **Get Code** button, which will prompt another dialogue box; then click on the *iFrame* tab and copy the code.
5. Copy the code contained within the *iFrame* tab.
6. Post and feature on desired section of web-app or [website](https://bucephalus.io/project/health-house-facebook360-photography/).

Although Facebook assures fellow developers that an easy WordPress integration will be released soon, as of this post, that remains to be seen; hopefully, we will see one soon for the sake of our clients because the solutions provided for the duration (subject example for WP):

```
<div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152795258318553" 
  data-width="500" da    enter code hereta-allowfullscreen="true"></div>
```

aren't exactly responsive and sometimes fail to render as expected.  Hope that helps!